# Why are requests for images still hitting my index.php file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp|js|css|map)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

My index.php file contains just the following:

```
<?php mail('me@mydomain.co.uk','Triggered','It was triggered'); ?>
```

I also have an image in the root directory "test.jpg"

The problem I'm having is that even though the .htaccess should be stopping when it gets one of the matched extensions (because of the L flag), it doesn't.

I know this because each time I access the image, even though the image displays correctly, it's also hitting my index file each time and I'm getting the mail through to my inbox.

Have I done something incorrectly in my .htaccess file?

Comment: Looks fine to me, I suggest you enable RewriteLogging. That allows you to learn what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine. Take a look at the documentation of the rewriting module to find out how to enable and configure that.

Comment: A peek into the access.log or including the real REQUEST_URI in your test mail might suffice even.